# Imagemap generator for huge project

Tags: html, imagemap, generator

I'm currently developing a game, where the user while registering has to pick where to live. I've generated a world, that I've seperated into multiple countries, which I then want the user to pick one of.

The world is a .png which I'm planning on image-mapping. My problem is, that this world has hundreds of countries, and thus it would take way too much time to make the image map by hand. Therefore I want a generator. I've looked into online sites like image-maps.com, but my problem is, that there's no way to save and continue work later, this is a VERY important feature. I've seen software such as MccImageMapper, but it doesn't mark my areas properly, and thus I can't see if I've missed anything.

Even better than image mapping software would be some software that could detect and create the image map itself from an outline map. I've seen stuff such as Svg2Imap, but I haven't managed to find one that worked just as expected as of yet.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: you could always try utilising bing or googlemaps API and overlaying your own map and co-ords. remember doing something similar myself in .NET a few yrs ago.

Comment: @James Sorry for the late response. How would I go around doing that? AFAIK the Google Maps API doesn't support custom maps.

Comment: I think I used the Bing one and changed the maptype to NULL. I then just drew my own one as multiple polygon shapes. was creating a map of a MMORPG game at the time ;-)

Comment: // Set the map to not display Bing Maps imagery map.MapType = MapType.Empty;    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846502.aspx

Comment: @Locercus - The free Google Maps API might not supoprt it but it the Google Map API actually does support it.

Comment: I will look into the Bing API. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: cool. let me know if either bing/google fits the requirements and I'll add as an answer ;-)

Comment: I took a look at the Bing API, and it didn't quite solve my problem. I looked into Inkscape Map, and it seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this handy tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscapemap. This combined with Inkscape seemed to solve the problem.

Thanks for your responses everyone!